# Devise: Restricting Actions to Administrators

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, action

Following the guide here, I added a boolean attribute to my database using a migration:

```
rails generate migration add_admin_to_user admin:boolean
```

I've configured my account to be an admin (admin = 1) via Rails console. I have a controller that I want to restrict access to certain actions (new, edit, create, and destroy) for administrators only.

I'll also have normal users, I just want to restrict access to these actions for admins only in this controller. Currently, I'm using the code:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:new, :edit, :create, :destroy]
```

Which restricts access to registered users -- how do I take this a step further and require admins?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

you can easily implement your own before_filter to allow access to only admin users by using the .admin? method associated with your user model.  for instance:

```
before_filter :verify_is_admin

private

def verify_is_admin
  (current_user.nil?) ? redirect_to(root_path) : (redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.admin?)
end
```

Answer (score 9):

You will want to define your own method in the before filter and then detect whether the user is an admin or not in that method prior to calling :authenticate_user!

```
before_filter :custom_method, :only => [:new, :edit, :create, :destroy]

private
def custom_method
  authenticate_user!

  if current_user.admin
     return
  else
     redirect_to root_url # or whatever
  end
end
```

You will want to do the authenticate_user! step prior to checking the current_user variable.

ian.

Comment: problem with calling this before authenticate_user! is that if someone who is not logged in at all tries to access it the filter will throw an exception as opposed to redirecting, since current_user is not defined

Comment: @Will: authenticate_user! will automatically redirect the visitor to the sign_in action if he is not logged in, so it would not even get to the if clause

Comment: I'd say personally this is the best approach. You keep the abstraction that Devise provides you with encapsulation and only then improve further. Your own code stays simple yet expressive.